# Overflow in horizontal sobel Vb 6.0

Tags: image-processing, vb6

I implemented the horizontal sobel detector in Vb 6.0 but I get "Overflow" error in the (grand) value, here is the sobel function I wrote :

```
Public Sub HorSobel()
Dim Op_X(-1 To 1, -1 To 1) As Integer, Op_Y(-1 To 1, -1 To 1) As Integer
Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer, i As Integer, J As Integer
'Pic5.Cls
Dim Grand As Double
Grad = 0
Op_X(-1, -1) = -1: Op_X(0, -1) = -2: Op_X(1, -1) = -1
Op_X(-1, 0) = 0: Op_X(0, 0) = 0: Op_X(1, 0) = 0
Op_X(-1, 1) = 1: Op_X(0, 1) = 2: Op_X(1, 1) = 1



For Y = 0 To Pic1.Height - 1
    For X = 0 To Pic1.Width - 1
        GradX = 0: GradY = 0: Grad = 0
        If X = 0 Or Y = 0 Or X = Pic1.Width - 1 Or Y = Pic1.Height - 1 Then
            Grad = 0
        Else
            For i = -1 To 1
                For J = -1 To 1
                PixelValue = GetPixel(Pic5.hdc, X + i, Y + J)

                GradX = GradX + (PixelValue * Op_X(i, J))

                Next J
            Next i
            Grad = Round(Sqr(Abs(GradX * GradX)))
        End If
        If Grad <= 0 Then Grad = 0: If Grad >= 255 Then Grad = 255
        SetPixel Pic6.hdc, X, Y, RGB(Grad, Grad, Grad)
        'Pic5.Refresh
    Next X
Next Y
Pic6.Refresh
```

End Sub

Comment: The Grand variable isn't assigned any value at all in the code you posted ... please use F8 to step into your code when the error occurs, and post which line actually fires the error

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the following variables in the code you provided:

- Grad
- GradX
- GradY
- PixelValue

If you declared them as Long or Integer, then it is possible that this is why you have an Overflow error.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you could provide the smallest amount of code that reproduces the issue, and will work without changing any code!